# Criterion for local systems

Tags: sheaf-theory

Given a sheaf on say a manifold, such that all its stalks are isomorphic to a fixed finite dimensional vector-space. 
Is it true that the sheaf is a local system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Let $M$ be your manifold and $p\in M$.  Let  $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space. The sheaf $S$ is defined as follows: for any connected open subset $U\subset M$, $S(U)=V$. (for not-connected $U$ we would then get a direct product of copies of $V$ - one for each component). If $U'\subset U$ is a connected open subset of a connected open $U$, the restriction map is as follows: if $p\in U$ and $p\notin U'$ then $S(U)\to S(U')$  is the zero map, otherwise it's the identity.

Comment: Thanks, your sheaf is even constructible right?